# Has calling StackAuth changed for Apps?

Tags: support, stackauth, c#, api-v1.1

I started upgrading to v1.1 and have an interesting problem I can't seem to resolve.

When calling `http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites` using a .Net WebClient I receive responses successfully and I am able to parse the results.

When calling `http://stackauth.com/1.1/sites` using a .Net WebClient I receive a `404 Server Error`. The same happens when making a call to `http://stackauth.com/1.1/users/1a41210e-1eea-47ad-a5d4-cacb00c6d027/associated` for any accounts associated to me.

The code between the two calls have not changed at all. Tracing the request in fiddler, it confirms the 404, however clicking on the link directly in a browser does however display the data as requested.

Interestingly, making a call to stats for 1.1 on any site outside of StackAuth seems to work perfectly.

Am I missing something important when making request to the 1.1 API on StackAuth?

**Solution**

For future reference. I was using `UploadString` and `POST` in the WebClient instead of using `DownloadString` and `GET`. Something I completely overlooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you by any chance using POST?

For 1.0 [this works](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites&http=1.1&type=POST). But [not for 1.1](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://stackauth.com/1.1/sites&http=1.1&type=POST) (though GET works fine for both [1.0](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites&http=1.1&type=GET) and [1.1](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://stackauth.com/1.1/sites&http=1.1&type=GET)).

(I have no idea if it *should* work though.)

Comment: Awesome. Between you and Rebecca I solved the problem!